# Inverse of a special hermitian sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, hermitian-matrices, sparse-matrices

While exploring some data modelling, I observed without being able to prove it that the inverse of matrix $A$ of the following form:

- it is hermitian, i.e. $A_{ij}=A^{*}_{ji}$
- it has non-zero positive elements over the diagonal, i.e. $A_{ii}>0$
- it has non-zero constant sub-diagonals $A_{kl} = f(k-l)$ with $f$ an arbitrary function of integer variable $n$, non-zero only for a few $n$
- it is zero elsewhere

is itself invertible and its inverse is within the same class of matrices. My questions:

1. Are these matrices part of a well-known class?
2. Is there any chance an inversion algorithm (or an analytical expression for the inverse) is available in the literature?

Please note that this is close but not equal to a sparse Toeplitz matrix, since the diagonal entries are all different, a priori.

Comment: Have you tried to write $A = D + T$, where $D$ is diagonal and $T$ is Toeplitz?

Comment: I am afraid I am not getting where this would lead?
The only attempt I would make is to use a special case of Woodbury's identity to obtain the inverse of $D+T$, which reads $(D+T)^{-1} = D^{-1} - (D + DT^{-1}D)^{-1}$. but I couldn't see how that implies the properties observed for $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Is solving a Toeplitz system cheaper than solving a general linear system?

Comment: Would you please more explicit with the aim of your question? Even though I might be interested in computationally efficient solutions, I am looking for exact proofs of what I have observed with a bunch of examples, hence question 1. and 2. in my post.

Comment: You have already found an analytical expression for the inverse of $D + T$.

Comment: Trying to use it to answer my second question:
$D^{-1}$ is easily inverted, because of it being diagonal. 
$T^-1$ is the inverse of a Toeplitz, which is not granted to be a Toeplitz itself.
Then inverting $D+DT^{-1}D$ has nothing special to be used.
I don't see how anything can be said about the inverse $(D+T)^{-1}$.

Comment: It's looking pretty hopeless. Are you acquainted with the [Levinson recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion)?

Comment: No I am not, but I realized that the out-of-diagonal terms are very close to the diagonal (i.e. $n=k-l$ is small), though. So maybe a better approach would be to invert many small matrices?

Comment: How many nonzero diagonals do you have?

Comment: The matrix can be as large as $10^4 x 10^4$, (it is the covariance matrix of a large random vector) with fewer than 10 nonzero diagonals on both sides, all very close to the diagonal itself, $n\approx4$.